# .netcore session variables always null

Tags: api, asp.net-core, session, session-variables

I have a .netcore 5.0 web api. And I want to implement session variables for users when logged in.
I believe I followed all the steps on multiple tutorials.

Here is what I've done so far
**Startup.c:**

[image]

[image: Configure method]

My controller class

[image: controller constructor]

I have a vuejs app, when I refresh the page I call "OnLoadPage", and when I click a button I call "OnPageGet".
Session variable seems to be set in the scope of the http call, but when I make another http request the session ID fully changes and all my variables are null.

What am I missing please help. Thank you.

[image: endpoints]

Comment: did we have the session cookie was present on client after first request ?

Comment: I'm not sure to follow what you mean. My user is authenticated, and I can see his claims. I expect to always have access to the authenticated user and it's session for each request. which doesn't happen for the session

Comment: `Authentication` cookie is not `Session` Cookie cookie, name of `Authentication` cookie is not the cookie name of `Session` cookie. As default, `Authentication` cookie name was `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme`, `Session` cookie name was `SessionDefaults.CookieName`. That;s why I asked... do we have that session cookie presented on client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized it's necessary to setup some cookie parameters to make it work.
In my developper tools I noticed an error on the response of my "PageLoad" request, where it said "samesite error" I just had to add this configuration parameter to my startup and it fixed it.

[image: session cookie parameters]

Comment: thanks for this! I spent several hours today thinking .NET Core 7's Session management was total crap. This fixed me right up.  Did you intentionally have SecurePolicy in there twice?

Comment: Glad it helped you. It's a mistake after a few long hours I guess I don't differentiate lines of codes.